# alertdialog with listview, check all and uncheck all button android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-alertdialog

have coded so far for alertdialog with listview and submit button but now i want to add "check all" and "uncheck all" buttons to my listview is it possible to add in alertdialog: listview,checkall button, uncheck all button and submit button with eventListeners to all the button plus listview adapter?. I surfed a lot all i could find is alertdialog with only listview and submit button.

Here's my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Select Category List");

                final ListView modeList = new ListView(getActivity());

                // Creating a button - submit
                Button btnDone = new Button(getActivity());
                btnDone.setText("Done");
                btnDone.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(
                        android.R.color.white));    
                btnDone.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.donebtn_with_bg);    
                final ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                        android.R.id.text1, EavesList);
                modeList.addFooterView(btnDone);    
                modeList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);    
                modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);                   
                for (int i = 0; i < EavesList.size(); i++) {    
                    if (selectedItems.size() != 0) {                            
                        for (int j = 0; j < selectedItems.size(); j++) {
                            if (EavesList.get(i).contains(selectedItems.get(j))) {
                                modeList.setItemChecked(i, true);    
                                j = selectedItems.size() + 2;
                            } else {
                                if (j + 1 == selectedItems.size()) {
                                    modeList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {    
                        Log.e("Selected Item ", "No Values");    
                    }
                }                   
                builder.setView(modeList);    
                final Dialog dialog = builder.create();    
                btnDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        selectedItems.clear();
                        eavesdropping.setText("");
                        SparseBooleanArray checked = modeList
                                .getCheckedItemPositions();
                        selected_community_id = new String[checked.size()];
                        String[] evas_id;
                        for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                            int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                            if (checked.valueAt(i))
                                selectedItems.add(EavesList.get(position));                             
                            selected_community_id[i] = EavesList_id
                                    .get(position);
                        }    
                            for (int i = 0; i < selected_community_id.length; i++) {                            
                            eavesdropping_hide.append(selected_community_id[i]);
                            if (i != selected_community_id.length - 1) {
                                eavesdropping_hide.append(",");
                            }    
                        }    
                        String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];    
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                            outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);    
                            eavesdropping.append(outputStrArr[i]);
                            eavesdropping.append(" | ");    
                        }    
                        dialog.dismiss();    
                    }
                });    
                dialog.show();
```

in above code i have added submit button as using addFooterView method of Listview..

here's how i want:[image: alertdialog must look same as this image]

so any tutorial or any idea or code related to this will help me. thanks in advance and sorry for long post.

Comment: is the checkall,uncheckalll and submit alertdialog is listview header or what

Comment: Yes you can why not.....

Comment: `it possible to add in alertdialog: listview,checkall button, uncheck all button and submit button with eventListeners to all the button plus listview adapter?.` yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that.On check all click you need to call adapter with values that will tell you need to check all check box in adapter.Similarly with uncheck case.
Both time you need to notify adapter to set again value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
When you click button in OnClickListener:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
          for (int i = 0; i < list.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
               final int position = i;
               mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                             list.setItemChecked(position, true);  
                      }
               });
          }
    }
}).start();
```

and in onCreate() :

```
this.mHandler = new Handler();
```

Each item in list view should be Checkable like CheckableRelativeLayout that implements Checkable interface.